# how to protect an activity in android

Tags: java, android, protected

I want to protect my activity class to not be allowed to use in another package, for example if have a user homepage activity it is should be able to called only if the user signed in correctly, but the `protected` is not allowed in android, so how i can do it?

Comment: Are you talking from end-user perspective or development perspective?

Comment: development perspective.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you but this sounds like a simple if,else block in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `android:exported="false"` for the activity in [your manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html):

> **android:exported**
>   Whether or not the activity can be launched by components of other applications — `"true"` if it can be, and `"false"` if not. If `"false"`, the activity can be launched only by components of the same application or applications with the same user ID.

Comment: Is there any way to make android:exported="false" global?